# Using 2012 ReportViewer winforms control in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2010, working on a WinForms application that uses the ReportViewer control to run a local report.  However, .rdl and .rdlc reports written using Version 3.0 of the language can't be run by this control.  This is a shame, because there are some features in 3.0 that would be darned handy.

I have read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/e609a329-58cd-4f30-b8d6-a912657d8eba/) that a new preview version of the control is out that would support 3.0.  It is associated with the VS2012 preview.

Does anybody know:

1. Whether a download for just the control exists, and
2. Whether VS2010 can build a project with this control?

(I know the VS2010 report builder doesn't work with v3.0, but I can live without that if I have runtime viewer support for it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for: [MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29024)

Answer (score 1):

There is an update to the Beta runtime posted above. Please see my post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2012/12/11/microsoft-report-viewer-2012-update-a-gotcha-to-be-aware-of.aspx for details.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate you providing the additional information!